# CSS position absolute and scroll issue

Tags: css, position, absolute

Im working on a website template and i want to make photo on the top.
Well I used the position absolute then I set top to -50px and left to -50px.
It work perfectly but I have one issue the scroll bar appear on bottom.
This is the css for the div :

```
#moon {
     background-image:url('img/moon.png');
     width:289px;
     height:289px;
     position:absolute;
     top:-150px;
     left:-160px;
     overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you put this background on the `body` element?

Comment: umm could you provide a jsfiddle or some more info what other elements are there, where does the scroll appear? on the body tag? if so then uses body{overflow-x: hidden;} <- this will remove the scroll on the bottom

Comment: @Itay ive already set abackground for the body , this div is just like logo and i cant use overflow:hiddeon on the boddy because the body is too long

Comment: Maybe you should try giving the body `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: @Itay Worked Perfectly Thanks Brother how can post it as answer so i can be able to choose as the correct one .

Comment: @checkopenport Could you please add a jsfiddle.net link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the body `overflow-x: hidden`

Also notice that on small screens there will be no horizontal scrollbar(!), unless you'll handle it specifically with responsive CSS.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much ! Worked